# Is there any way to break a router's password?

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios, network

I want to change the configuration of a router but a password has been set. Is there any way to troubleshoot, coz no one knows the exact password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but it requires rebooting the router and having console access. You can google "cisco password recovery" for detailed instructions.